# Prevent users from writing other user's data in node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have three different types of users in my node-js schema:
1 -> user, 2 -> merchant 3 -> provider

Now i am giving only merchant users to post the data about parking.

I have this query in node.js to update the parking data:

```
exports.updateParking = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { parkingId, parkingName, price, address, name, phoneNumber, about } =
      req.body;
    const check_exist = await Auth.findById(req.data.id);
    if (!check_exist) return res.status(404).json({ error: "User not found" });

    const updateData = await Parking.updateOne(
      { _id: parkingId },
      {
        $set: {
          parkingName,
          price,
          //...other details
        },
      }
    );
    return res.status(200).json({
      success: true,
      msg: "Parking has updated successfully",
    });
  } catch (error) {
    return error.message;
  }
};
```

I am using JWT to authenticate the users.
Here is the middleware: `routing.patch("/parking/update/:id",middleware.authenticateToken,merchant.updateParking);`

How to alter the above query such that only the original poster(merchant user) may edit the details and that anybody else cannot.

Comment: How do you identify individual users? Must they log on to your server?

Comment: Yes, first they sign up.

Comment: But how are the subsequent requests then authenticated, if you don't use sessions? Can you share some more of your code?

Comment: I am using jwt to send the request. Here is the request ```routing.patch("/parking/update/:id",middleware.authenticateToken,merchant.updateParking);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the request is authenticated with a JWT `token`, you can obtain the user (probably their email address) as

```js
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var user = jwt.decode(token).sub;
```

If you store the user in every `Parking` entry, you can make sure that every user can only see or change their own entries.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm unsure of how this operates and where to insert the code you just created.

Comment: You can [search this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bexpress%5D+JWT+authentication) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can check current session userid vs request body

```
if(req.session.userid !== req.data.id){
  return res.status(403).json({ error: "Forbidden" });
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am not using sessions here I am authenticating users by JWT

Comment: You can encode userid into jwt payload in the header.